# Convert to DateTime from string containing decimal and comma millisecond separators 

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Given the following 2 strings notice the ".185" and ",185"

- `2011-09-15 17:05:37,185`
- `2011-09-15 17:05:37.185`

Reading from a file (not in my control) and I can see they have dates in both formats. I need to create a function that cater for both scenarios.

Is the '**.**' and '**,**' a culture specific?

Any suggestion for such a function?

This below is not working as I don't get a date.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string date1="2011-09-15 17:05:37.185";
        string date2="2011-09-15 17:05:37,185";

        const string format1 = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff";
        const string format2 = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,ff";
        DateTime resultDate1;
        DateTime resultDate2;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, format1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDate1);
        DateTime.TryParseExact(date2, format2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDate2);
         Console.WriteLine(resultDate1.ToString());
         Console.WriteLine(resultDate2.ToString());
         Console.Read();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Use DateTime.TryParseExact().

Comment: I think . and , are culture specific

Comment: see my edited question I dont get a date at all

Comment: @user231465, that's just sloppy. `dd/MM...` and `2011-09...` don't match. :)

Comment: @bzlm .Wrote quickly.I am reading a file that is not in my control and date1 and date2 is how it's written in this file.Do you have any suggestion how to best read those dates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the . and , a culture specific?

Yes. In Europe,  a comma is often used instead of a period as the decimal separator.

> Any suggestion for a solution?

Yes. My first thought is that the DateTime.ParseExact()/DateTime.TryParseExact() functions have an [overload that allows an *array* of formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) to test. You could include both the en-US variant and the en-GB variant. Except that I don't think this will work, as you still only get to include a single culture specifier.  So instead, I recommend calling .Replace() before passing the string to ParseExact function to change any commas that might be in the string to periods.

In your updated example code, your format string just doesn't match your example dates. You should use this:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff

Comment: thanks for your reply. Edited my question with an example.What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JoelCoehom.Thanks. Read article and helped + suggestion dateFormat.Thank you

Comment: @user231465, use the tab completion when writing @ replies. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use DateTime.ParseExact or .TryParseExact as suggested in Hans Passant's comment.

```
DateTime d1;
string[] formats = new [] { "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff" };
DateTime.TryParseExact(s1, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                    DateTimeStyles.None, out d1);
```

You should also specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, as otherwise the ParseExact method may use a culture-specific date separator (in place of /, e.g. "." in Germany) or time separator (in place of ":").

Comment: Thanks.After read the article as suggested in previous answer I did exactly what you suggested.